# Accessing global dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

I don't think there's much explanation to this, the problem is straight forward. I get an error saying
Edit: I added the full error traceback at the bottom.

Error:

```
"if i in items:
NameError: name 'items' is not defined"
```

code:

```
class Cart:
items = {}
def addToCart(item):
    global items
    for i in item:
        if i in items:
            items[i] += item[i]
        else:
            items.update(item)
            
def removeFromCart(item):
    global items
    for i in item:
        if i in items and items[i] > 1:
            items[i] -= 1
        elif i in items and items[i] <= 1:
            items.pop(i, None)
```

How the function is called:

```
...
from .cart import Cart
...
@action(detail=True, methods=["POST"])
def addToCart(self, request, pk=None):
    item = request.data['item']
    Cart.addToCart(item)
    response = Cart.items
    return Response(response, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Internal Server Error: /api/Orders/1/addToCart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "/home/bigmac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bigmac/Documents/Bernard_Quests/ALUTA3.0/ALUTA/api/views.py", line 89, in addToCart
Cart.addToCart(item)
File "/home/bigmac/Documents/Bernard_Quests/ALUTA3.0/ALUTA/api/cart.py", line 7, in addToCart
if i in items:
NameError: name 'items' is not defined

Comment: First, items should be indented to match Cart class. And we don't know if two methods are part of Cart class(I think so though).

Comment: A class attribute is not global and I guess your dictionary should actually be an *instance* attribute. Additionally your methods are missing the `self` argument.

Comment: `items` looks like a class attribute. Use `Cart.items` instead of global variables. Also I assume the methods `addToCart` and `removeFromCart` belong to the class, Why are you not accepting `self` as an argument? Or at least using a `classmethod` decorator and accepting the class as `cls` or some other name?

Answer (score 0):

try this

You should also declare **items** in the global scope before it is used.

```
class Cart:
   items = {}
   def addToCart(item):
       global items
       var_items = items
       for i in item:
          if i in var_items:
            items[i] += item[i]
          else:
            var_items.update(item)
            
   def removeFromCart(item):
      global items
      var_items = items
      for i in item:
         if i in var_items and var_items[i] > 1:
            items[i] -= 1
        elif i in var_items and var_items[i] <= 1:
            items.pop(i, None)
```

Refer this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement

Comment: This will give the same error, nowhere is items defined in the global scope before it is used. Perhaps more important, items shouldn't be global at all but an instance variable, using global variables in a class defeat the fundamental purpose of a class